# Conditional code works badly

Tags: shell

My conditional code does not work properly. Why?
My aim is that if the file does not have the characters rfd, it does not run the next command which is sed. But, every time, using any wrong or right file, it gives me the echo Unsuccessfully you! Why? How to fix it? and it runs the next command. How can I resolve this problem and write this shell script in a way that the next command only runs if my condition is successful?

```
echo $file
if 
else 
    echo Unsuccessfully you!
fi
```

Comment: by next command, it can be any command like sed, grep, cut,etc...any of them shows the same thing to me.

Comment: Do you want to look for "rfd" in the filename, or in the file's contents?

Comment: You need to learn what pipes are used for.  They are not there to combine operations but to pass data from one process to another.

Comment: rfd in content of file

Comment: @JIGIL: Thank people for good answers by upvoting them, and, if it’s on your question, accepting the best answer.  And you may post a comment, when you have earned that privilege.  Do not write a new answer just to say “Thank you.”    ***And DO NOT EVER VANDALIZE AN ANSWER as a technique for saying “Thanks.”***

Comment: In case future archeologists wonder what that last comment was about, let the record show that [the author of this question](/users/219474) was using the name “JIGIL” when he or she suggested [this edit](/review/suggested-edits/186389) to [DopeGhoti’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/352174/80216#352175) on Mar 17, 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments to an earlier form of this answer, the desire is to act upon files which have an `r`, `f`, and `d` in them.  So we have some options.

With `grep`s:

```
if grep -q 'r' '/path/to/file' && grep -q 'f' '/path/to/file' && grep -q 'd' /path/to/file; then
    echo "The characters are in the file; acting accordingly."
else
    echo "The characters are not found in the file; acting accordingly."
fi
```

Comment: it still has problem. I want all rfd be shown in the file. But, grep here only considers any of them, generating wrong echo as a result. How to change my grep command?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Do you want to display any instances of `rfd` found in `file`?  If so, remove `-q`.

Comment: if my file has the content like this:   rfs drg  rft  ftr

Comment: that is the file I want to keep, but not the file that is like : rtf fzr  tsq   because it does not have the character d

Comment: Do you know how I can solve it? Thnx

Comment: So.. you want to act on any files with an `r`, an `f`, _and_ a `d` in them?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: @reader, if this answer solves your problem, click the checkmark to indicate so; don't edit "thanks" comments into the answer.